# IOS Rate this app implementation

Tags: ios, iphone

***How to implement the Rating Application feature in ios.***

Can anyone guide me on how to implement it?
Is there any way to open the **review tab** directly on RATE App clicked.

Answer (score 2):

See this [here](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-add-write-a-review-rate-us-feature-to-your-app/) & [here](http://www.ideveloperblog.com/tutorial-how-to-properly-use-and-implement-a-rate-my-app-library/). i think it might be helpful in your case.

**EDIT:**
You can also use [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate) ([Steps](http://www.binpress.com/app/irate-prompt-users-to-rate-your-app/616)).